# Не пойму что не так с заданием от преподавателя по python

Tags: python

Задание:

> Поменяйте значения переменных местами в том случае, если значение первой переменной больше значения второй в 3.6 раза, либо значение второй находится в промежутке
> [(-138/2)^1.3 ; |(-69/28^5.1)*4|].

Мой код

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
if (a / b==3.6) or (abs(b > (-138 / 2) ** 1.3) and b < (abs((-69 / 28 ** 5.1) * 4))):
    c = a + b
    a = c - a
    b = c - b
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: `abs(b > (-138 / 2) ** 1.3)` ничего не смущает ? например знак сравнения внутри функции abs ... Ну и в `(a / b==3.6)` аналогично

Comment: Смущает возведение отрицательного числа в дробную степень

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте это

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())

if (a / b==3.6) or ((-138 / 2) ** 1.3 <= b <=-69 / 28 ** 5.1* 4):
 a, b = b, a
print(a, b)
```

Comment: `a / b==3.6` так делать нельзя. Либо сразу decimal, либо проверка с некоторой точностью